# How can I get rid of the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <modulename> error?

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bookList' when trying to run the bot I wrote. In the bkmBooks.py file, I imported my model " from bookList.models import BookList " in this way. However, after the migrate, the functions inside my bkmBooks.py file did not work. What might be causing this error?

The order of file structure is as follows:

bookList>bookfiles>bkmBooks.py

Contents of my bkmBooks.py file:

```
from ast import Str
from base64 import decode
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv
from time import sleep
from random import randint
import numpy as np
from bookList.models import BookList
# import bookfiles.bkmBooks as bkmBooks

headers = dict()
headers[
    "User-Agent"
] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"

def sendBooksToMysql():
      bkmArt()
def bkmArt():
      pages = range(1, 3, 1)
      for page in pages:
            url = "https://www.bkmkitap.com/sanat"
            results = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, "html.parser")
            book_div = soup.find_all("div", class_="col col-12 drop-down hover lightBg")
            sleep(randint(2, 10))
            for bookSection in book_div:
                  img_url = bookSection.find("img", class_="lazy stImage").get('data-src')
                  name = bookSection.find("a",class_="fl col-12 text-description detailLink").get('title')
                  author = bookSection.find("a", class_="fl col-12 text-title").get('title').replace('Model:', '')
                  publisher = bookSection.find("a", class_="col col-12 text-title mt").get('title').replace(name, '')
                  price = bookSection.find("div", class_="col col-12 currentPrice").text.replace('\n', '').replace('TL', ' TL')
                  b_link = bookSection.find("a").get('href')
                  
                  bookList = BookList.objects.using("bookList").update_or_create(
                  site_name="Bkmkitap",
                  site_id="1",
                  image=img_url,
                  #book=name,
                  #author=author,
                  publisher=publisher,
                  price=price,
                  link=b_link,
                  category_name="Sanat",
                  category_id="1",
                  defaults={             
                        "site_name":"Bkmkitap",
                        "site_id":"1",
                        "image":img_url,
                        "book":name,
                        "author":author,
                        "publisher":publisher,
                        "price":price,
                        "link":b_link,
                        "category_name":"Sanat",
                        "category_id":"1",
                  }
            )
```

Contents of my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class BookList(models.Model):
    site_name = models.TextField()
    site_id = models.TextField()
    image = models.TextField()
    book = models.TextField()
    author = models.TextField()
    publisher = models.TextField()
    price = models.TextField()
    link = models.TextField()
    category_name = models.TextField()
    category_id = models.TextField()
    class Meta:                                                                                                                                                        
        managed = True
        db_table = 'books'
```

Comment: is the _\_init_\_.py file present in both folders?

Comment: There is init.py file in bookList folder but not in bookfiles @Trafalino

Comment: you should start from top level module using absolute path

Comment: "However, after the migrate, the functions inside my bkmBooks.py file did not work": that's a different error than ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: You're showing a lot of (unnecessary) Python code, but not how you are running your script, nor where the script is located. Also consider using a bit more ASCII art to show the structure of your setup better, so that it's easier to place all the files in the directory structure. Something like [this example on the right](https://ascii-tree-generator.com/).

Comment: I added a photo of my file structure, is that what you're talking about? @9769953

Comment: No, I mentioned ASCII, or just plain text. Pictures can be hard to read, like this one (small, grey and blue on a black background). Besides, there is no context, just a random picture. Please make it a good question, instead of trying to do the least amount of work possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your imports don't work together, I think:

```
from bookList.models import BookList
# import bookfiles.bkmBooks as bkmBooks
```

For the first one to work, you should be on top level, for the second one inside `bookList`. Also bookfiles seems to be missing `__init__.py`.

Comment: How can I add the init.py file to the bookfiles folder? Also is "from bookList.models import BookList" a wrong import? @miriess

Comment: Just add an empty textfile `__init__.py` to the directory. That is needed for the folder to be considered a python module.
When you start your script from the top level, then `from bookList.models import BookList` should work. But then `import bookfiles.bkmBooks as bkmBooks` won't work because that is a path relative to the `bookList` directory.